# Powershell find matching cell in .csv and apply commands for the the matching cell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

[image]Right up front, I want to say I have 0 knowledge of Powershell. I'm taking a chance to see if someone out there could help me.

I've been tasked to create a script that will look into a CSV file, run through each row, and based on the location of a User apply certain policies.

Example

CSV Contains

```
Name      Number           Location
ironman    +123456789        USA
superboy   +456987654        UK
Blackwidow 00789456798       Asia
```

1. After successful Login into MS Teams PowerShell:
2. Apply Policy 1 to all Users in the .csv File

   - Look at the UPN and assign the Telephone Number
   - Enable Enterprise Voice
3. Look at the Location of each UPN and apply the matching Policy
   E.g.1 ironman is in the USA, therefore he gets assigned Policy 2 – USA Attributes
   E.g.2 superboy is in the UK, therefore he gets assigned Policy 3 – UK Attributes
   And so forth
   If there is no policy for the location, write a message: Policy doesn’t exist.

[image]

Comment: What should happen next? What does "policy assignment" entail? Do you just want to add a new column to the CSV with the designated policy name?

Comment: Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72630018/edit) with the relevant code (easier to format nicely than in a comment) :)

Comment: But now I need to assign different policies to users based on their location. So have a separate policy instead of -PolicyName Global, it must be based on where the User location is.

hope this makes sense.

Would appreciate if i could email you a Visio drawing and current script if you could provide your email address.

Comment: No need, your explanation makes sense :)

Comment: Thank you kindly, really appreciate the help. Busy testing it out and will post outcome soon.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hashtable to create a "mapping" between different locations and their relevant policy names. Then all you need to do is check whether the location in question has an associated mapping and apply that:

```
$policyMappings = @{
  'USA'  = 'Policy 1'
  'UK'   = 'Policy 2'
  'Asia' = 'Policy 3'
}

foreach($user in Import-Csv .\path\to\users.csv){
    # fetch the identifying information already in the CSV row
    $upn = $user.userprincipalname
    $phone = $user.Phonenumber

    # resolve the policy name
    if($policyMappings.ContainsKey($user.Location)){
        $policy = $policyMappings[$user.Location]
    }
    else {
        # default to the global policy if no mapping is found
        $policy = 'Global'
    }
    
    Set-CsUser -Identity $upn -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true
    Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity $upn -PhoneNumber $phone -PhoneNumberType DirectRouting 
    Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -PolicyName $policy -Identity $upn 
    Grant-CsTeamsCallingPolicy -PolicyName $policy -Identity $upn
}
```